# Can I run specfic scripts in multiple DB server?

Tags: sql-server, flyway, database-mirroring

I am using flyway for Database migration and want to achieve the following scenario :

I have one use case in which I need to fire all scripts in single SQL DB server except one script which needs to be triggered on another SQL DB server.
The purpose behind this situation is to achieve DB mirroring.
Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Comment: Are these one time scripts? What I mean, can you execute them from SSMS just once or you need some kind of automated process that would automatically fire these scripts?

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev no this will be repeatative script, and its only 1 script. As you know I am using flyway for this, I have assign R versioning in script name. I don't want SSMS in this scenario as scripts will get executed on application startup. So I want some script based solution that can connect another server from it self and then execute further query on given database of that server. I am insisting through query because flyway executes SQLs pretty same way as SSMS